# Regex getting subgoups

Tags: python, regex

I have faced with the following issue:

```
change = "1,23 2,54 1,85 "
results = re.findall(r"((\d+),(\d+) )+((\d+),(\d+) )+", change)
print(results)
```

Results are:

```
('2,54 ', '2', '54', '1,85 ', '1', '85')
```

But I want something like this:

```
('1,23 ', '1', '23', '2,54 ', '2', '54', '1,85 ', '1', '85')
```

I have not found any solutions unfortunately

Comment: Explain why you use the third and sixth `+` and (only) twice the `((\d+),(\d+) )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repetition of the regex group is redundant. You should simply use 1 and just do `findall`. I've used the `itertools.chain` but you could achieve it by simple list comprehension too.

```
change = "1,23 2,54 1,85 "
results = re.findall(r"((\d+),(\d+) )", change)
print(results)
# [('1,23 ', '1', '23'), ('2,54 ', '2', '54'), ('1,85 ', '1', '85')]
from itertools import chain
print(list(chain(*results)))
# ['1,23 ', '1', '23', '2,54 ', '2', '54', '1,85 ', '1', '85']
# simple list comprehension
print([single for group in results for single in group])
# ['1,23 ', '1', '23', '2,54 ', '2', '54', '1,85 ', '1', '85']
```

Comment: If you want to pass the result to the `chain` you could also use `re.finditer()` which returns an iterator rather than a list.

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil: Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```
change = "1,23 2,54 1,85 "
results = [n for t in re.findall(r"((\d+),(\d+))", change) for n in t]
print(results)
```

The output:

```
['1,23', '1', '23', '2,54', '2', '54', '1,85', '1', '85']
```